# How do I get an icon to always appear on the right in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment with an actionbar and one icon, and another fragment which is placed over the first one with it's own actionbar and two icons. I have it so the second fragment will show all three items in the actionbar and the first one shows only it's one:

[fragment with 3 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKKUX.png)

[fragment with 1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD2My.png)

I'd like the red square in the fragment with 3 items to be on the right hand side of the other two items.

Fragment layout for 2 items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_sort"
        android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sort_24">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Distance"/>
            <item android:title="Salary"/>
            <item android:title="Date Posted"/>
        </menu>

    </item>
    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_filter"
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Freelance"/>
            <item android:title="Zero Hour"/>
            <item android:title="Part Term"/>
            <item android:title="Internship"/>
        </menu>
    </item>



</menu>
```

Fragment layout for 1 item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="@string/menu_profile"
        android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/profile_menu_layout"/>

</menu>
```

Profile_menu_layout used above:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        >


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by setting the `android:orderInCategory` on the menu items. [For reference.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource).

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help. :)